# Is an ingenious engine engineer a genius?

Tags: etymology

How are these words related from an etymology point of view?

- engineer
- engine
- ingenious (here the 'i' and 'e' positions are swapped)
- genius

Comment: The first "engineers" designed catapults and the like, for military use.

Comment: Etymonline also relates _engineer_ to _ingenium_. Before the Industrial Revolution, _engine_ could refer to a very simple mechanical device. A military engineer built things like battering rams and also fortifications; a civil engineer built roads and bridges.

Comment: @KateBunting - Yep, and the military engineer came first.  "Civil" was pre-pended to differentiate from the military engineer (someone who designed "war engines").

Comment: @mins - That's not really how it derives.

Comment: @mins I fear you are on the wrong track of false friends: "Based on the verb ingénier, from Old French engigneor, itself from engin or from Medieval Latin ingeniator or ingeniārius (“one who makes or uses an engine”), from Latin ingenium (“an engine”), from in (“in”) + gignō, gignere (“to produce, cause”). The distinction was likely intentionally made to separate the word from the unrelated Old French engigneor (“deceiever”). Source https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ing%C3%A9nieur#French

Comment: engineer, engine, ingenious and genius: why bring French into this??

Comment: Back around 1970, when I was in engineering school, it was explained to us that an "engineer" was someone who built "engines", which were devices of war.  So the term "engineer" initially had a military connotation.  Thus, when engineers employed their mechanical abilities to design projects (bridges, etc) for civil use, they were called "civil engineers", to differentiate them from engineers of the military kind.  My recollection is that this terminology first arose in Greece.

Comment: in French, "C'est **un génie**" means "He's a genius"; **La génie civile** in French means **civil engineering**. I would avoid referring to French for these words you are interested in. It just confuses the issue. That said: **ingenious** (clever or smart)  in French is: **ingénieux or ingénieuse**

Comment: Et bien alors il suffit de voir ce que dit le CNTRL à ce propos: 3. id. génie des Ponts et Chaussées (ibid.). Empr. au lat.genius « démon tutélaire qui préside à la conception, donc à la destinée d'un homme »; le sens de « caractère » est attesté dès le lat. du Bas Empire (TLL s.v., VI, 2, 1831). Le sens III est dû à l'infl. de ingénieur*. Cad, génie et ingénieur sont liés.

Comment: @mins - When all this was transpiring a "device" (by whatever name) was a catapult or battering ram.  Engineering didn't get any more subtle than that.

Comment: Et aussi, le génie d'une langue, par exemple, et pas seulement du français. Allez, j'arrête lá. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's merely attempting to justify a predetermined "answer".